# Norm of a difference - Convergence of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider that $z_k \in \mathbb{Z}^m$, for $k = 1, 2, \ldots$, and that $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mid\mid z_{k} - z_{k-1}\mid\mid_{\infty} < 1.$$

Without any assumptions about monotonicity, is it sufficient to affirm that $z_k \rightarrow z_{k-1}$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and that the sequence $z_k$ converges to a constant vector?
The first part seems trivial, but the second is not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: both parts are trivial

Comment: What do you mean by $z_k \rightarrow z_{k-1}$? Do you mean $z_k - z_{k-1} \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Yes, I guess that the condition above in $\mathbb{Z}^m$ is sufficient to affirm that $z_k - z_{k-1} \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @terrace please, could you explain me how is trivial the second question?

Comment: @MichaelLee We have $z_k \in \mathbb{Z}^m$. In that space, your construction doesn't work. // Guido: for $v,w \in \mathbb{Z}^m$, what does $\lVert v - w\rVert_{\infty} < 1$ imply?

Comment: @DanielFischer What I mean is that $\mid \mid v - w \mid \mid = \underset{i = 1,\ldots,m}{\text{max}} \mid v_i - w_i \mid < 1$. But each component of such vectors is integer, than what I expect is that $\underset{i = 1,\ldots,m}{\text{max}} \mid v_i - w_i \mid$ can only be 0. And this holds for all the components, so $\mid \mid v - w \mid \mid = 0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I should have read more closely. Well, in that case, $\|z_k-z_{k-1}\|_{\infty} < 1$ is possible only if $\|z_k-z_{k-1}\|_{\infty}$, so I guess both statements are trivially true, since $\lim_{k\to \infty} \|z_k-z_{k-1}\|_{\infty} < 1$ implies $\lim_{k\to \infty} \|z_k-z_{k-1}\|_{\infty} = 0$, which implies that there is some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|z_k-z_{k-1}\|_{\infty} = 0 \Rightarrow z_k = z_{k-1} = z_N$ for all $k > N$.

Comment: You are not wrong. Indeed the condition implies $z_k = z_{k-1}$ for all large enough $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the condition $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \|z_k - z_{k - 1}\|_\infty < 1$ is indeed sufficient to show that $z_k$ is eventually constant (and hence $z_k - z_{k-1}$ converges to $0$). In essence, this is because, if $\|x - y\|_\infty < 1$, then $x = y$. To see this, consider
$$\|x - y\|_\infty < 1 \implies \forall n \in \lbrace 1, \ldots, m \rbrace, |x_n - y_n| < 1.$$
Since $x_n - y_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and the only integer whose modulus is strictly less than $1$ is $0$, it follows that $x_n = y_n$ for all such $n$, so $x = y$.

Back to the main problem, the rest is $\varepsilon$-$N$ argument. Let:

\begin{align*}
L &:= \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \|z_k - z_{k - 1}\|_\infty, \\
\varepsilon &:= 1 - L > 0
\end{align*}
By definition of the limit, there must be some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that,
\begin{align*}
k > N &\implies |\|z_k - z_{k-1}\|_\infty - L| < \varepsilon \\
&\implies \|z_k - z_{k-1}\|_\infty - L < \varepsilon \\
&\implies \|z_k - z_{k-1}\|_\infty < L + \varepsilon = 1 \\
&\implies z_k = z_{k-1}
\end{align*}
Thus $z_k$ is constant from $z_N$ onwards, and hence convergent.